# Can't deserialize JSON object using custom deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
  "Properties": {
    "String": "one-string-value",
    "Number": 123,
    "LiteralList": [
      "first-value",
      "second-value"
    ],
    "Boolean": true,
    "ReferenceForOneValue": {
      "Ref": "MyLogicalResourceName"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use Jackson to deserialize it into a proper `Map<String,Property>`. For this i'm using `TypeReference` like so:

```
public class Template {

    @JsonProperty("Properties")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = PropertyDeserializer.class)
    public Map<String, Object> propertyList;
}

public class PropertyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Property>> {
    public Map<String, Property> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String,Property> result =
                mapper.readValue(jsonParser, new TypeReference<Map<String,Property>>() {});

        return result;
    }
}
```

Each `Property` can only take some values: strings, ints, booleans, a list of strings, or another object which has one key "Ref". So I wrote this:

```
public class Property {

    private Object value;

    public Property(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Property(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Property(List<String> values) {
        this.value = values;
    }
    public Property(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Property(Ref reference) {
        this.value = reference;
    }

}

public class Ref {

    private String reference;

    @JsonCreator
    public Ref(@JsonProperty("Ref")  String reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work:

1. For the `LiteralList` property, I get the error **Cannot deserialize instance of `Property` out of START_ARRAY token**
2. For the `ReferenceForOneValue` property, I get the error **Cannot construct instance of `Property` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)**

I have uploaded all the source code [here](https://github.com/miparnisari/jackson-demo).

Can someone help me write a deserializer for this?

Comment: what is the output you are expecting ?

Comment: @Deadpool for 1), since I have provided a constructor for `Property` that accepts `List<String>`, I expected it to be used. For 2) I expected a property to be created where its `value` is an object of type `Ref`

Comment: Sorry i don't really get your question, I don't know why you have multiple constructors overriding same property value with different types. Actually you just need specific information from that json file ?

Comment: @Deadpool Because each `property` of the json can have different types: string, int, list, etc., so I provided one constructor for each type. Maybe there is a better way of doing this, I don't know. I don't want to allow _any_ type, just the ones that I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 4):

A valid approach is to write your custom creator:

```
@JsonCreator
public Property(JsonNode node) {
    switch (node.getNodeType()) {
        case STRING:
            value = node.asText();
            break;
        case NUMBER:
            value = node.asInt();
            break;
        case BOOLEAN:
            value = node.asBoolean();
            break;
        case ARRAY:
            Iterator<JsonNode> elements = node.elements();
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while (elements.hasNext()) {
                JsonNode element = elements.next();
                if (element.isTextual()) {
                    list.add(element.textValue());
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("invalid data type");
                }
            }
            value = list;
            break;
        case OBJECT:
            try {
                value = new ObjectMapper().treeToValue(node, Ref.class);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("invalid data type", e);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("invalid data type");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, it uses Java reflection to match property constructor to json data type. I had to modify the property constructors a bit to match Jackson deserialization (use wrapper types instead of primitives). Also, reference type is built from Map (`Reference` class is stripped of all Jackson annotations)

Property class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Property {

    private Object value;

    public Property(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Property(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Property(List<String> values) {
        this.value = values;
    }

    public Property(Boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Property(Ref reference) {  // not used
        this.value = reference;
    }

    // reference is received as map 
    public Property(Map<String, String> map) {
        if (map.containsKey("Ref")) {
            this.value = new Ref(map.get("Ref"));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid reference property");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

Template class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Template {

    @JsonIgnore
    public Map<String, Property> propertyList = new HashMap<>();

    // map of data type from json to property constructor
    private static Map<Class<?>, Constructor<Property>> propertyConstructors;

    // build propertyConstructors map
    static {
        propertyConstructors = new HashMap<>();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Constructor<Property>[] constructors = (Constructor<Property>[])Property.class.getConstructors();
        for (Constructor<Property> ctor : constructors) {
            if (ctor.getParameterCount() == 1) {
                propertyConstructors.put(ctor.getParameterTypes()[0], ctor);
            }
        }
    }

    @JsonProperty("Properties")
    public void setProperties(Map<String, Object> jsonProperties) {
        if (jsonProperties == null  ||  jsonProperties.isEmpty()) return;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> property : jsonProperties.entrySet()) {
            Optional<Constructor<Property>> optionalCtor =
                propertyConstructors.keySet().stream()
                    .filter(argType -> argType.isAssignableFrom(property.getValue().getClass()))
                    .map(argType -> propertyConstructors.get(argType))
                    .findFirst();
            if (optionalCtor.isPresent()) {
                try {
                    propertyList.put(property.getKey(), optionalCtor.get().newInstance(property.getValue()));
                } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid property " + property.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the deserialization is straightforward:

```
Template t = mapper.readValue(in, Template.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is using reflection the only solution? I'm worried that it overcomplicates things..

Comment: I couldn't get jackson to properly deserialise ref

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Jackson doesn't like the whole List interface.

```
public class Property{

//...

  public Property(String[] list){
    this.value = list;
  }
//...
```

or if you WANT a List object:

```
public class Property{

//...

  public Property(String[] list){
    this.value = Arrays.asList(list);
  }
//...
```

or simply go with @cassiomolin's answer